# Decimal to Binary Conversion for Long Values

Tags: java

I am using below method to convert a Decimal to Binary.
The method expects a long type as a parameter and returns the Binary equivalent.
But if a value like "2147483647L" is passed as an argument, it returns some garbage value.
What exactly I am missing out in this code fragment ?

```
public long calculateBinary(long N){
        long m=N, s=0, i=0;
        while(m>0)
        {
            long k=m%2;
            s=(long)((Math.pow(10,i)*k)+s);         
            i++;
            m=m/2;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: If what you're actually returning is a `long` whose decimal representation _looks like_ the binary expansion of another number, it won't take long before you pass the maximum size of a `long`.

Comment: Use BigInteger or String in return statement!!!

Comment: If you are trying to manually create the binary representation of a number, you should be returning a string.

Comment: `N` already is binary, and your code doesn't convert decimal to binary correctly. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Khelwood : I even tried returning the string using the _Long.toBinaryString(long)_ method present in the api. But when I tried parsing the value to long it resulted in _NumberFormatException_

Comment: @EJP : The value of N is _"2147483647L"_ in the above example. Just wanted to get its binary equivalent using the given code fragment.

Comment: The value of `N` is held in the computer in binary the moment you execute its initialiser. The compiler does the decimal to binary conversion. Uncelar what you're asking.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to coerce a binary representation into a `long` variable. A _binary representation_ is a string. `Long.toBinaryString` does what you need.

Comment: @EJP : I understood your point. That's exactly how computer works. But i wish to convert the given decimal number to binary programatically.

Comment: Then you need to represent the input number as a string for a start. Otherwise the job has already been done for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, which takes into account sign and binary representation:

```
public String calculateBinary(long N) {
    boolean direction = (N >> 63 === 0);
    String result = (direction ? "" : "-");
    for (int bits = 0; bits < 63; bits++) {
        result += direction ? ((N << (1 + bits)) >> 63) : (1 - ((N << (1 + bits)) >> 63));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is inaccurate to say that the `long` is already converted into binary, since there is a huge difference between the computational representation of binary numbers and their effective value, since the binary representation of a long variable differs from the effective mathematical binary representation of a number in case the number is negative.